# MSSql - Select statement not working on all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

In mssql Management studio, when I rightklick -> select all rows, it generates automatically a select statement and executes it to show the content of the table. In one particular table it is not working. it says that the columns do not exist.. The select statement has all columns between brackets like this:

```
SELECT [col1]
  ,[col2]
  ,[col3]
  ,[col4]
  ,[col5]
FROM [Line01].[dbo].[QtyInfo]
```

in this particular query, newly added columns 4 and 5 do not work. in order to make them work i have to write it without the brackets. 
like this:

```
SELECT [col1]
  ,[col2]
  ,[col3]
  ,col4
  ,col5
FROM [Line01].[dbo].[QtyInfo]
```

why is this happening only to some particular tables?

Comment: This is strange.  The automatically generated code should be correct.

Comment: What do you mean with "do not work"?

Comment: @HoneyBadger it says that the column does not exist.. but it exists as soon as I remove the brackets

Comment: *"newly added columns 4 and 5 do not work"* You haven't refreshed the object explorer since you added them, and thus the generated script won'tr incldue them.

Comment: *" it says that the column does not exist"* With respect, i don't beleive that. `Col4` and `[Col4]` are synonyms, If a column with the name `Col4` didn't exist, both statements would generate the same error: `Invalid column name 'col4'.` The brackets (`[]`) are simply delimit identifiers. Like putting something in quotes (`"`).

Comment: Does it complain the columns don't exist when you execute the query, or is it just the red line in the IDE?

Comment: @HoneyBadger in the IDE

Comment: *"in the IDE"* Then you haven't refreshed intellisense (and probably the object explorer). Intellisense doesn't constantly refresh (that would be a huge burden on the server), you have to refresh it manually.

Comment: @sharkyenergy - Press the ctrl + shift + R to refresh the IntelliSense local cache. It will detect the recent changes and should identify the columns.

Comment: In SSMS navigate in object-explorer -> databases -> your database -> tables, right-click on QtyInfo and hit refresh. Now the columns should be available in your query editor...

Comment: What's the SSMS version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellisense is a very helpful feature that is part of multiple Microsoft products, like SQL Server Management Studio, Visual Studio, and others. It helps reduce time searching for table names and columns and other database objects by adding an auto-complete suggestion menu as you type in your code.

- **Verifying that Intellisense is enabled:**

  In order to check that SQL Server Management Studio Intellisense is working properly, the first thing we need to check is that IntelliSense is enabled. In order to do this we need to follow the next steps:

  1. Go to `Tools` > `Options`
  2. Then navigate to `Text Editor` > `Transact-SQL` > `IntelliSense`
  3. Make sure that all the checkboxes are ticked so that all features of IntelliSense are enabled and working
- **Refreshing Intellisense:**

  In order to refresh IntelliSense we have to do one of the following two options:

  - In a query window, make sure to press the following key combination: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
  - Go to `Edit` > `IntelliSense` > `Refresh Local Cache`